# How do I make this render look more realistic, need most help with texturing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, texture-painting, photorealism

[image: This is just terrible, I don't understand how texturing photorealism works]

I really need help with this, thank you so much.

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: it is supposed to be an apartment building

Comment: I was wondering what material it is supposed to have.

Comment: For the texture of the apartment, try a PBR material that you can download from sites like https://www.sharetextures.com/category/concrete. There you find various materials.
-- 
With an *RGB Curves* node you can adjust the diffuse color as you like. Use the normal map and the roughness map. The Ambient Occlusion (AO) map is usually mixed with the diffuse color. -- To get rid of the repetitive pattern have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VgtSL5ZpYc (Uber mapping node)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no help with the texturing/shading, but I have some basic architectural advice - however you handle the windows, they should be lots darker. If you don't want to show reflections off the window glass, not a biggie, but unless it's night time, and the lights inside are on, the rooms behind the windows will be pretty dark compared to outside. Hope that helps.